# Attempting to Register Entity Framework and Data Providers inside a DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to fully register the Entity Framework and Data Providers inside of a DLL using **code-based configuration**. The goal is to not have to include any references to the entity framework in the application and allow the initialization of the DLL to handle the entity framework registration.

I have found a few links and I feel like they have helped some, but I am still feeling that I am missing something.

I read that "Code-based configuration in EF6 and above is achieved by creating a subclass of System.Data.Entity.Config.DbConfiguration." I have created a class called MyDbConfiguration which inherits the DbConfiguration class and created a constructor method which is where I will set the configuration options. Also, I have read that I need a DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on my context class and I have included this in my context class. 
(Information found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx)

Currently inside my MyDbConfiguration constructor I attempt to:

- set the default connection factory

  Me.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(New System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"))
- set the Sql provider

  Me.SetProviderServices(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance)
- set the MySQL provider

  Me.SetProviderServices(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices)

My **problem** is that I am having trouble configuring the application to not include references to the entity framework in the application. When I include the references to `MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6.dll`, `EntityFramework.dll`, and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` in my project it all seems to work. When these references are excluded I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException occurred
```

`A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'occurred in MyProject.exe`

`Additional information: Could not load file or essembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ...'`
`or one of its dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified.`

Anyone have any insights to what I have to do to not include the references in my application?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to "obfuscate" dll's away ;)

I would suggest to return ONLY Lists and other "common" types if you don't have any reference to System.Data.Entity .

Creating Services should be the way to go, eg. ( short example without real code)

```
public class ProductService{
    public List<Product> GetProductsBySearchterm(string q);
    public List<Product> GetProductsByBarCode(string q);
}
```

Then there are 2 ways to go:

2 dll's ( prefererred)

- Seperate your Entity framework from your domain layer and combine it in your data layer ( eg. look for 3 tier or 4 tier development for more info). Then add the Domain dll + Service DLL to your application. The service layer only returns object types from your domain layer.

or 1 dll ( not preferred, but as little dll's as possible)

- Add DTO's to your project, the services call your Entities and transform it into the responding DTO's. The DTO's are inside your service layer.